# Bitbucket: Find all unmerged branches by a user

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am using Bitbucket and want to find all my unmerged branches as they need to be looked at and deleted if not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

On a local clone, to list the branches where you are the author of the head commit(*), you can use :

```
# for local branches:
git log --no-walk --branches --author="my@email.com" --oneline

# for remote branches:
git log --no-walk --remotes --author="my@email.com" --oneline
```

---

The `--oneline` in the examples above is just a formatting directive, you may change it to anything you like.

For example:

```
git log ... --format="%D"
```

will print just the branch(es) name(s) pointing at the selected heads, and no other information.

The output should be close to a script input, it may need a bit of editing before sending it to a script, as you may see :

- `HEAD -> my/branch` for the active branch
- `foo, origin/foo` if two branches (or a remote + a local branch) point at the same commit

See [`git help log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) and its ["Pretty Formats"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) section for all the details.

---

(*) git stores information in commits (author, author date, committer, committer date ...), there is no such thing as a "branch" object though, so there isn't a notion of an *owner* of a branch; getting the author of the latest commit looks like a reasonable approximation.

Obviously: if you have a workflow where the "owner" of a branch is supposed to mention his name (or his trigram, ...) in the branch name, just list `git branch` or `git branch -a` and look for your trigram there ...

Comment: this command also gives all deleted branches I am looking for all active branches which could be deleted

Comment: @Varun Sukheja: in your comment, what is an "active branche" ? also: have you tried running `git fetch --prune` on your local repo ?